# Someone did something in Google+, but what did they do?

Tags: google-plus, notifications

What actually happened when the Google+ notification says a contact "did something"?

Here's a screenshot of the notification I see in Gmail about G+ activity:

[image: notifications drop down]

> Rahul yadav added you on Google+.
>   Gaurav Tripathi & Nilesh did something.

But what did the contacts on the second line actually do? Does this wording mean anything in particular?

Another example:

[image: did something mention]

**Edit** : Now, That notification is modified as follows.

[image: New Modified Notification]

I assume

> "They did something = They added me into their circles"

Comment: Does this show up on another browser ?

Comment: @Binarylife - Hmm ! Its not browser specific. I found it in each browser.

Comment: It's not a typo, it is "something" with an O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got this notification in GMail, while on Google Plus I got a notification those contacts added me back.

It is possibile that this is a new notification type previous versions of the notification counter didn't have support for, and thus "did something" is what they fall back onto.

Comment: did you notice my modified/edited question ? I added a new snap-shot there.

Comment: @sugar Next time a new kind of notification is added, though, it'll still show up as "did something." :)